# In reference to statistics as it relates to information about research?

Tags: single-word-requests

Academia.SE is working on retagging `statistics` and I was trying to figure out if I was missing a word on the tip of my tongue. [Here's the original thread](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/how-to-disambiguate-the-statistics-tag).

These are the three definitions for statistics we have:

- Questions on "standards and conventions specific to statistics as an
  academic discipline, and programs leading to a degree in this field."
  For example, Should I do a PhD or Master in Statistics for a career
  in Data Science?
- Questions on "the use of statistics in academic
  research. Statistics is the science of collecting, analyzing and
  drawing inference from data." For example, Should I cite all R
  packages I used? This is the use currently specified by the tag wiki
  excerpt, which reflected the actual use of the tag at the time that I
  last edited it, but doesn't seem to now.
- **Questions asking for
  statistics about research or academia.** For example, Can you get
  statistical data on research paper submissions and publications?

I've proposed the first two as `statistics discipline` and `statistics in research`.

The one in bold is the one I am struggling to come up with an appropriate word for. I would prefer that it be a noun. I proposed `statistics-meta` (metastatistics), but that is probably more confusing than it needs to be. I'm looking for a word that can be used similar to the two I've written above that relates to the last bullet point. Is there a word for this?

Comment: "Statistical practice"?

Comment: _Academic statistics_?

Comment: In statistics, there is the term [*meta-analysis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis), which sort of aligns with this notion.

Comment: For a tag I'd go for statistics-request.

Answer (score 1):

It's already present in the question (in your example), but have you considered:

**statistics about research or academia** can be summed up as

> statistical data

As the fact it's *about research or academia* is already fairly clear in the context

Answer (score 0):

At least for research papers and books you can use the term — **bibliographic data**.

For citations you can use the terms **citation index** or **citation data**.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it is still important to present the field in the same manner you present your other fields.  (Unless you plan on changing your other fields to "biology discipline", etc.)

1. Statistics
2. statistical science
3. statistical data

In contrast (or possibly at the same time), it may be more useful to break the single original "statistics" into two separate tags rather than trying to give it one tag.  The usefulness of tags is often on *including* more information with a single tag rather than excluding more.